# Cannot get mobile nav to reappear

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to toggle my navbar from displaying by adding and removing a css class with a display:none attribute. My js will add the class, but not remove it preventing the nav from hiding.

```
<div class="hambugerMenu">
   <i class="bars"></i>
</div>

<div id="mobileNav" class="mobileNav">
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

```
.mobileNavHidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```
document.querySelector('.hambugerMenu').addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    hideShowNav()
})

function hideShowNav() {
    var nav = document.querySelector('#mobileNav')
    if (nav.classList.contains("mobileNav")) {
        nav.classList.add("mobileNavHidden")
    } 
    else if (nav.classList.contains('mobileNavHidden')) {
        nav.classList.remove("mobileNavHidden")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nav` still has the `mobileNav` class so the first if-statement is firing and not allowing the else-if-statement to run. You could change it to check if the `mobileNavHidden` is there first and then decide what to do with it.

Ex

```
if (nav.classList.contains("mobileNavHidden")) {
    nav.classList.remove("mobileNavHidden")
} 
else {
    nav.classList.add("mobileNavHidden")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function

```
function hideShowNav() {
    var nav = document.querySelector('#mobileNav')
    if (nav.classList.contains('mobileNavHidden')) {

      nav.classList.remove("mobileNavHidden")
    } 
    else {
         nav.classList.add("mobileNavHidden")
    }
}
```